# How can I abort a call to redis after a specific time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I have a function where I would like to call specified redis methods which currently errors if it times out after a specified time in `ms`.

```
  const redis = require('redis');

  const client = redis.createClient({ url: process.env.REDIS_URL || 'http://localhost:6379'});

  const callRedis = (fn, timeoutLimit, ...args) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => reject(new Error(`Command timed out after ${timeoutLimit}ms`)), timeoutLimit);
    client[fn](...args, (err, res) => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(res);
      }
    });
  });
```

how can I adjust the above code to ensure the specified `fn` gets aborted once the `timeoutLimit` is reached?

I've found that I can create a `new AbortController()` which also gives me the `signal` property but I'm unsure how to use this with/in the `callRedis()` function?

EDIT: an example use of `callRedis()`:

```
const { callRedis } = require('../redisService.js');

const ONE_SECOND = 1000;

try {
  const someCachedValue = await callRedis('get', ONE_SECOND, 'someKey'); 
} catch (err) {
  console.log('Redis call timed out!');
}
```

Comment: Are you using node-redis v3 or v4?

Comment: @LeibaleEidelman v3